# How can i change stripe subscription payment page design?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, stripe-payments

The subscription payment page is aligning in one line i need to show it like a normal payment form show card number , cvv and expiry on multiple lines rather than one line
i m attaching an image to show how it looks
[stripe image before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReIiK.png),
[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRmFx.png)

my code is as follow

```
  var stripe = Stripe('Publishable Key');


 var elements = stripe.elements();
  
  var style = {
 base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4'
      },
      display:'block'
  },
  invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
  };

        
      // Create an instance of the card Element.
      var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});
      card.mount('#card-element');
```

please advice

Answer (score 0):

I recommend upgrading to [Stripe Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element), which looks like what you are looking for, but also comes with a lot other nice features, such as letting you accept up to 40+ payment methods with a single integration. You can also fully customize the style with the [Elements Appearence API](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api).

Comment: i need to use a custom one because of the payment system that is already integrated

Comment: What do you mean by `custom one`?